# How to use entity framework in business layer and/or data layer?

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework

I would like to use entity framework in my asp.net application.

I can use Linq to entities in any layer, but I would like to know where should I put Entity Framework? (DAL, BAL or direct use in Presentation).

Comment: Are you familiar with the ORM concept then?

Comment: @o.k.w. Yes, But if i implement EF in DAL, should i create Business Objects and transform EF objects to BO objects and use them in BAL and presentation layer?

Comment: @Krunal: While I guess Furis answered already.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

EntityFramework should go in the Data Access Layer. To expose it up to the presentation layer tightly couples your presentation to the database, allowing changes at the database level to flow up to the presentation layer.

What we have done on some of our projects is to use entity framework at the DAL, transform the entities to our business objects (which are actually quite simple object primarily used as DTO's as most of our logic is contained in services that act on the objects - this route isn't for everyone, but it fitted with what that architecht wanted).

Comment: Should i create Business Objects and transform EF objects to BO objects and use them in BAL and presentation layer? Is this the only way?

Comment: It is not the only way, but in my opinion it is the best way. It will help you reduce coupling, as well as help with the seperation of concerns. If you were to use EF objects on the BAL / Presentation layer, where would you put your business logic?

Comment: @Furis - Agreed, can you provide some sample code for one class.

Comment: What section of code would you like a sample of? The transformation to a business object?

Comment: @Furis - Yes, if you explain the same thing with sample code that would be helpful.

Comment: Ok, I will prepare a sample and post it a bit later.

Comment: Thanks Craig. @Krunal, sorry I didn't get around to posting the code sample, I had some difficulties accessing my SVN remotely.

Answer (score 0):

This is a one of the best practices that I have used for Entity Framework in data and business layers

**1- In Data Layer**

We will create a generic repository class for all required Entity Framework functions

**2- In Business Layer**

Now the Entity Framework is ready to use in Business Layer